# Word Usage - "Yourself"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, reflexives

Is is correct to use the word *yourself* as follows in a sentence?

> Can you please set up a meeting tomorrow with Tom, Shaun, Rupert and yourself?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Can you tell us why you think it is right or wrong?

Comment: Would "You" in this sentence be grammatically correct versus "Yourself"?

Comment: Yes. ----------

Comment: This should be a duplicate of [Reflexive pronoun use when subject is a subset of the prepositional object](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343627/), but that earlier question doesn't have any answers, so I can't cite it in a closevote.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Erm well it looks like it, but actually it seems to make a big difference whether the coordinates are mixtures of pronouns and other types of noun or just pronouns. (When it's just pronouns the reflexive doesn't seem to be necessary).

Comment: @Araucaria: Indeed. Mostly, the *presence* and *type* of other (pro)nouns (and *sequence*) affect the ***stylistic merits*** of using a reflexive form, rather than the "syntactic validity". But whereas (ignoring any potential ambiguity) *John only bought tickets for him and his wife* seems perfectly valid to me, I can't help thinking *John only bought tickets for him* and *John only bought tickets for his wife and him* are so awful there's probably some actual "rule" against it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, indeed. I think it's pretty complicated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reflexive pronoun use when subject is a subset of the prepositional object](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343627/reflexive-pronoun-use-when-subject-is-a-subset-of-the-prepositional-object)